# Is it bad to update a a list of a size greater than 200 in DML

Tags: dml

I am reading the existing code in the project. In the code:

```
if(aUpdates.size() + aList.size() > 200) {
     update aUpdates; aUpdates.clear(); aUpdates.addAll(aList);
} else {
     aUpdates.addAll(aList);
}
```

Does this piece of code really make sense? I can't recall anything if it is bad to use DML for a list of size greater than 200.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It used to be a limit enforced by the system, so in older code you'll see this kind of thing everywhere. For the last few years though we've not needed to bother with it; I can't remember which release it was exactly mostly because I didn't even realise at the time and continued to do this for some time after.

Comment: Even more so, you can now even combine lists of up to 10 types of sobjects into a single update.

Comment: Yeah, that's proved to be super helpful. I'd love some kind of release-specific lint tool, that can identify older constructs in code and suggest new fixes. It'd be a very complicated problem but some kind of static compilation and tracing could help for sure.

Comment: I'm working on some tools like that, actually.

Comment: That's awesome, please keep me posted on progress!